# using _GET url link to delete a record from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html, get, pdo

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help so far. I have edited my post to reflect the changes suggested below. I am using PDO for my database connection. The code I have now is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<a href="includes/delete-customer.php?userID='.$row->customer_id.'">
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php

    //MySQL Database Connect
    include 'includes/config.php';

        // confirm that the 'id' variable has been set
        if (isset($_GET['userID']) && is_numeric($_GET['userID']))
        {
                // get the 'id' variable from the URL
                $id = $_GET['userID'];

                /* Delete row from the customer table */
                $id = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM customer WHERE customer_id = '$id'");

                $stmt->execute();
        }
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'user';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=testDB", $username, $password);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

I'm pretty sure the HTML is correct now and the issue lies with the delete-customer.php file. I am currently receiving the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object

I'm not sure of how to implement the PDO query correctly. Any further advice is much appreciated.

Comment: @Morgan thanks for your reply. I have just updated the html link with what I thought may be the problem but it is still not deleting the record from my database. Any further ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Please check the answer I posted below. Why are you adding a literal $id to your querystring argument?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML section says:

```
<a href="includes/delete-customer.php?customer_id=$id['.$row->customer_id.']">
```

Is this your exact HTML syntax? This argument should be the actual numerical id, i.e. --

```
<a href="includes/delete-customer.php?customer_id=3">
```

-- either by echoing `$row->customer_id` (assuming it exists), or some other method of knowing that user id.

Your HTML only needs to send the actual data, not any sort of variable syntax. Your receiving PHP (`$_GET['customer_id']`) will interpret that for you and properly pass that to MySQL.

Comment: I have fixed up the HTML section to read the following:<a href="includes/delete-customer.php?userID='.$row->customer_id.'">. It now appears to be outputting the correct link. I am now getting to following error from my php file:Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() ... on line 13. I have also applied @Christain Varga's solution below.

Comment: `Call to a member function prepare() on non-object`? You may need to edit your question and share the contents of 'includes/config.php' - looks like `$mysqli` isn't being initialized the way we would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL passes `userID` as the get parameter, yet in your php script you're trying to access `customer_id`. Try changing your code to retrieve `userID` and it should work

```
if (isset($_GET['userID']) && is_numeric($_GET['userID']))
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian I have fixed up my HTML and PHP in line with the suggestions above but I am getting the following error with my PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare()...line 13

Comment: How is your database connection being made? Post up some code for the database connection

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="includes/delete-customer.php?customer_id=<?php echo $id[$row->customer_id]; ?>">
```

assuming $id[$row->customer_id] is valid.

Plus, you really shouldn't delete from database on get var unless you're doing some admin validation / access rules and guarantee you don't have anyone on the job who will go rogue and manually type in numbers there.. That's just plain crazy.

Comment: I was surprised how many answers I skimmed past before seeing @Kai Qing's warning about allowing $_GET requests to delete records. I couldn't find a link to the story, but there was a big article on someone who's entire database was destroyed by an otherwise well behaved bot. DON'T DO IT!

Comment: @TecBrat thanks for the feedback, could you provide me with a link to the best practices for deleting records from my database using a direct link? many thanks.