# Deleting row using PDO Php

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to delete a row using PDO but unable to delete the row and am clearly mis understanding something here.

Here is the link that will allow me to delete the row:

```
<a class="deleteMember" href="actions/delete.php?doc_id="'.$docs['doc_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></span>
```

So it should pass the doc_id from that row to the delete.php file which is below:

```
 <?php

    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='******';
    $password='*****';

    try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);

$sql = "DELETE FROM `doc_list` WHERE doc_id != :id_to_delete";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );

$query->execute(array(":doc_id" => $doc_id));

?>
```

But once executed I am confronted with a white screen.

```
So doc_id is defined from here:

try {

$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
$sql = "DELETE FROM `doc_list` WHERE doc_id != :id_to_delete";

$query->bindParam(':id_to_delete', $doc_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();



if ($query) {
    header ('Location: ../docList.php');
}
else{
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the docList.php file

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>



<?php 

require_once '../../db_con.php'; 

try{
    // Selecting entire row from doc_list table
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM doc_list ORDER BY doc_updated DESC");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$docs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>



<div class="container">

<br>

<h3 class="subTitle"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></span> Document List
    <a href="newDoc.php"><span class="addNew" title="Add New Document"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></span></a>
    <a href="newEmployee.php"><span class="addNew" title="Add New Category"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span></a>
</h3>  



    <span class="trow">
        <span class="tableHeadersLarge">Doc Title</span>
        <span class="tableHeadersMed">Created Date</span>
        <span class="tableHeadersMed">Last Updated</span>
        <span class="tableHeadersSmall"></span>
    </span>



<?php

    foreach($docs as $docs){
        echo
        '<span class="trow">
            <span class="tableHeadersLarge"><a href="docEdit.php?doc_id='.$docs["doc_id"].'">'.$docs["doc_title"]. '</a></span>
            <span class="tableHeadersMed date">'.$docs["doc_created"].'</span>
            <span class="tableHeadersMed date">'.$docs["doc_updated"].'</span>
            <span class="tableHeadersSmall">
            <a class="editMember" href="docEdit.php?doc_id='.$docs["doc_id"].'"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a>
            <a class="deleteMember" href="actions/delete.php?doc_id='.$docs["doc_id"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></span>
        </span>';
    }
?>



</div>
```

Comment: Turn error reporting on. You're getting an error somewhere.

Comment: `:doc_id` != `:id_to_delete` Almost the same, but not the same!

Comment: where and how is `$doc_id` being defined?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have updated my question - I am a little confused as to how or where it gets the ID in order for it to delete the row

Comment: Your connection is `$dbh = new PDO` - `$dbh` but all your queries are `$db`; did you make the change for all of them?

Comment: I have updated it again, can you spot what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: and this `$query = $db->prepare( $sql );` did you not change that to `$query = $dbh->prepare( $sql );`?

Comment: and this `WHERE doc_id != :id_to_delete` that means **where it does NOT equal**, you sure you didn't mean `WHERE doc_id = :id_to_delete`? as in **equals that ID**

Comment: This is becoming really confusing now - could you show me what I should be changing from delete.php as a whole so I can understand?

Comment: as per your edit, you're not executing anything in your delete.php file. nor are you binding anything.

Comment: I have just made some changes please see

Comment: Your delete.php is incomplete and has many errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and then clean up each error. For instance, you opened a `try` block and did not complete it.

Comment: then you just put `$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];` where it **doesn't belong** again. It belongs in delete.php - sorry, but I don't know where else to throw myself here. You're just going all over the place.

Comment: in what file is `<a class="deleteMember" href="actions/delete.php?doc_id="'.$docs` this in and how is it being used and queried? I'm trying real hard to help you, but you keep changing stuff around and it's confusing me; a lot.

Comment: Well at this point, I found a Q&A that has a solution with the accepted answer. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/27578184/ then just replace the DB stuff with your own and the accepted answer. I don't know what else to do or say that will be of further help; good luck.

Comment: So that link is in a page which lists out rows from ym database - see my question for that file

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the wrong placeholder in your query `:id_to_delete` and `:doc_id`:

We have no idea where or how `$doc_id` is being assigned, therefore I'm taking a blind stab at saying you need to assign like this:

```
$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];
```

`actions/delete.php?doc_id` that is a GET method, therefore you need to use what I included just above.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `doc_list` WHERE doc_id != :id_to_delete";
$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];
// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:**

This `WHERE doc_id != :id_to_delete` that means **where it does NOT equal**. Are you sure you didn't mean `WHERE doc_id = :id_to_delete`? as in **equals that ID**

You also have a typo in:

```
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
```

that should be `$dbh` and not `$db`.

As per your connection:

```
$dbh = new PDO...
```

while making sure you're using the same variable everywhere for it.

> *"But once executed I am confronted with a white screen."*

That means you have syntax errors somewhere.

Use error reporting and exceptions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit:**

Instead of:

```
$query->execute(array(":doc_id" => $doc_id));
```

Try:

```
$query->bindParam(':id_to_delete', $doc_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

if that column is indeed an `int`.

---

**Edit #2:** (last ditch effort)

delete.php

Make absolutely sure that your `doc_id` column is an `int` type and that you've indeed chosen the right database. `dashboardr` seems questionable with the `r` at the end.

```
<?php

    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='******';
    $password='*****';

    try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_GET['doc_id'])){
$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM `doc_list` WHERE doc_id = :id_to_delete";


$query->bindParam(':id_to_delete', $doc_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Where it says 'id_to_delete' am I leaving that as that or does this need to be changed to the ID I want to delete and if so how will it know which Id I want to delete? Just change it to doc_id ?

Comment: @user3725879 Your `SELECT` query should be set in a `while` loop. See this answer for an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/22538164/ and this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/9595045/

Comment: @user3725879 however, if your present query returns a bunch of rows, then that may be OK too. Have you tried deleting with my fixes?

Comment: I have indeed however it keep giving me the white screen so its opens a new page provides te id of the row as expected but it does not action the php inside of the delete.php file I will update my question so you can see my delete.php file

Comment: @user3725879 a blank screen means syntax errors. Reload my answer again and look under **Add error reporting to the top of your file....** on how to check for errors in your file(s).

Comment: I have included everything you have suggested above, the error reporting returns nothing on that page...

Comment: @user3725879 use error reporting on all pages.  Plus, `$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];` that belongs in delete.php not in the other file. You should also have marked your edit AS an edit. You overwrote your question and I stand at being downvoted for it.

Comment: $doc_id = $_GET['doc_id']; that is in the delete.php file

Comment: @user3725879 I don't know what else to do here. But reload my answer and look near the end under **Edit:**

Comment: I have made the changes, please see my question I will mark as an edit

Comment: @user3725879 reload my answer and look under **Edit #2: (last ditch effort)** - I've tried, Lord knows I tried. Good luck.

Comment: I just dont understand the id_to_delete part is that meant to stay like that or?

Comment: @user3725879 just try it.

Comment: still gives me the white screen and the row still exists, dashboardr is correct btw also the doc_id is an INT

Comment: @user3725879 reload it again, I did a bad paste for `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` there was a missing semi-colon and it should have been under the connection. Just goes to show how confused I am at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Typo within your code

```
$query->execute( array( ":id_to_delete" => $doc_id ) );
```

it should be

```
$query->execute(array(":doc_id" => $doc_id));
```

Comment: I missed the first one in my answer ^^

Comment: Its ok we can identify as much as possible

Comment: There's still an error in the first one it should be `<a class="editMember" href="docEdit.php?doc_id="'.$docs['doc_id'].'">` assuming they have wrapped it in `echo '` judging by `class="` they have.

Comment: That might be possible @Last1Here. But can't say it surely

Comment: In fact there does not seem to be an error in the original code for the link. They are just using `echo '` as oppose to `echo "`

Comment: Hi Guys, I pasted in the wrng link I am so sorry please see my updated question

Comment: @user3725879 update your link tag is it within PHP or simple HTML

Comment: its inside of PHP yes

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $db->prepare( 'DELETE FROM `doc_list` WHERE doc_id=:doc_id' );
$query->execute( array( ':doc_id' => $doc_id ) );
```

Hi,

You executed it wrong, you replaced ":id_to_delete" to the doc_id, while you were in need to replace ":doc_id". Also use '' for queries and strings etc.

**Difference between '' and ""**

"" is also checking for variables, so '' are some faster.